# How to connect google cloud shell to termux app using ssh?

Tags: shell, ssh, cloud, google-cloud-shell

I am using `google-cloud-shell` which is basically a shell that allows us to use *online cloud shell (for developing apps etc.)* and provides `5gb` of free storage (only for *home directory*).
It is a very cool thing because i don't have PC but `google-cloud-shell` allows me to run *gradle, java, python, etc.* without any issues except one issue and i.e typing response. Although it is a very good platform for learning coding but typing is insane.
If i type a character it takes about a second to be displayed on screen and it really really sucks. Now what i want is to connect this shell to `termux` (which is an app just like terminal in linux) with `ssh` or any other thing that can connect it.

**NOTE: I am not using paid version of `google-cloud-storage` I am just using it `cloud shell` which is free to use.**

[image: Screenshots of google-cloud-shell]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following gcloud command to SSH into your cloud-shell from local terminal.

```
gcloud alpha cloud-shell ssh
```

You can find more details [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-the-ability-to-connect-to-cloud-shell-from-any-terminal)